# React Native: Adding borderColor creates subtle box shadow

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a React Native app, and have a profile component that looks like this:

[image]

The container has `backgroundColor: '#fff'`, and the pencil icon has `borderColor: '#fff'`.

As you can see, however, the white on the border of the pencil does not match the background color, and there is subtle artifacting around the border of the pencil.

Does anyone know how I can make the border of the pencil icon match the background color exactly? Any suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This aliasing is due to the presence of `backgroundColor: #444` on the element that has the `borderColor: '#fff'`. Removing that background color makes the border color a perfect white.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2017